# Why is the marginal pdf of $x$ constant? $x$ is the coordinate of the points uniformly distributed on the surface of a sphere

Tags: probability

Consider a sphere of radius $R$ centered at the origin with points uniformly distributed on the surface. What is the marginal pdf of the x-coordinate of these points?

Apparently the answer is

$$
f_X(x) = \frac{1}{2R}
$$

This is very unintuitive for me because I would think this $f_X$ would be dependent on $x$, and would be largest at $x = 0$ tapering off as x increases/decreases.

Comment: The marginal is the distribution of the dot product of the coordinates with the unit x vector $(1,0,0),$ which is why the answer is found in one of the duplicates concerning scalar products.  This result is correct for the sphere in three dimensions only: it underlies the most basic equal-area maps of the earth.

Comment: Also asked at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3788624/321264